# Adding Arraylist object to hash table in java

Tags: java

how to store multiple arraylist objects in hashtable in java
& how do i get it back.

Comment: Do you mean multiple ArrayLists for the same key? or does each ArrayList get its own key (as in Murali's answer)?

Comment: -1 Question is vague and sounds like the submitter never even bothered to look at the Map or Hashtable documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Don't. Use [HashMap](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) instead of Hashtable - it's not synchronized.

```
Map<String, ArrayList<SomeObject>> myMap = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<SomeObject>>();
ArrayList<SomeObject> list = new ArrayList<SomeObject>();
list.add(someObjectInstance1);
list.add(someObjectInstance2);
myMap.put("key1", list); // stores list containing instances #1 and #2 under key "key1"
ArrayList<SomeObject> list2 = new ArrayList<SomeObject>();
list2.add(someObjectInstance3);
myMap.put("key2", list2); // stores list2 containing instance #3 under key "key2"

SomeObject obj1 = myMap.get("key1").get(0); // returns instance #1
SomeObject obj2 = myMap.get("key1").get(1); // returns instance #2
SomeObject obj3 = myMap.get("key2").get(0); // returns instance #3
```

All that said, you may want to consider using [Multimap](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) from [Google Collections](http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/) instead:

```
Multimap<String, ArrayList<SomeObject>> myMap = ArrayListMultimaps.create();
myMap.put("key1", someObjectInstance1);
myMap.put("key1", someObjectInstance2);
myMap.put("key2", someObjectInstance3);

SomeObject obj1 = myMap.get("key1").get(0); // returns instance #1
SomeObject obj2 = myMap.get("key1").get(1); // returns instance #2
SomeObject obj3 = myMap.get("key2").get(0); // returns instance #2
```

You can see how much more straightforward this approach is.

Comment: The code above does not add <b>multiple</b> arraylist objects in a <b>Hashtable</b>

Comment: I would think that it'd be pretty obvious how to add a 2nd (3rd, Nth) list to the map by looking at the above code but apparently I was wrong. Updated to illustrate two lists.

Comment: There I reverted my downvote, hope you feel better.

Answer (score -1):

Use the Hashcode of each Linklist as the Key. Using a FOR Value mentioned in one of the posts as the Keys is probably not a good idea. What if you have to add a new List somewhere else ? You will have to traverse the entire map to find the next greatest key.

Comment: using the hashcode of the linked list as a hash key is a horrible idea. First of all, it has no meaning to the application. The only reason for putting things into a hashtable (as opposed to a list for example) is to be able to look them up by key. Second, there are lots of collisions: If you put in three empty lists, they would override eachother. Third, you should never use a hash key that can change, and the hashcode of a list changes as the list contents change.

Comment: Thilo, Your answer is very good. My mistake, I assumed that the Hashcode will be equal to the address in the memory where the List is stored and hence Unique.